# how to convert PDF to XML

Tags: java

I am facing problem finding any solution for converting my PDF to HTMl/xml.This requirement comes because I have a certificate as a PDF form.I need to make this certificate available to the user in the form of a HTML page(specifically using JSF). User can edit this form and can update the values.These values will be read by backing bean so that I can be saved in the database.Problem is these certificates kept on changing after 3 months or so. So if I go by trivial approach of writing all the components in the HTML, I will be kind of hell to maintain and to change. So I want that if there is any JAVA utility which I can tweak so that I can render the page using XML.

Looking forward for the answer. 
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a try: [pdftohtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/). It looks pretty old, latest release is from 2006.

If you need just the raw text: consider using [itext](http://itextpdf.com/), parse the raw text and fill it into a xml document.

Comment: hello Andreas .. thanks for pointing these available softwares. can you please put some light on how can I use PDFBox for the same.